# Hide an href link if the user is logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery. I have following `a` links in the page header

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/home.html?sign=true">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/jobs.html">Tests</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vps.html">Jobs1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ust.html">Jobs2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/sub.html">Subscription</a></li>                  
    </ul>
</div>
```

This header is included in the common `index.html.` When a `sign in` page arrives I am using this common header. My problem is while the user is trying to enter the `sign in` page he seems the `home page` link also.

I need to hide both `home page link` and `subscription link` in the sign in page. How can I hide these two `a` elements?

Comment: If your user is signing in to your site, you should do this on the server side, based on their session credentials, not in javascript.

Comment: is there any possibility to do in jquery.

Comment: It is entirely possible, but it won't stop people looking at the source of the page to see where they need to go to get into login-restricted pages. Also, if they have javascript disabled, your security goes out of the window.

Comment: i mean i have session variables for signed user name and other details.so using this how can i hide the link details

Comment: Just saving in cookies or local storage, however this should REALLY be done in server-side. Doing this in client-side would be a crime for humanity, for real.

Comment: you could check the status of the `session variable` and write an if condition for the required `a` tag.

Comment: make a variable _loggedin, When _loggedin == true then the link is not avalible for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Set id to that both home, subscription link and place the following jquery in the sign in page header.

    jquery
    ------------------------------------
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#link1,#link2").hide();
    });    
    </script>

    html:
    ---------------------------
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="link1"><a href="/home.html?sign=true" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/jobs.html">Tests</a></li>
            <li><a href="/vps.html">Jobs1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ust.html">Jobs2</a></li>
            <li id="link2"><a href="/sub.html">Subscription</a></li>                  
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view model class to your view and assign it to view. You can pass a model to your view from controller by setting `IsSignedIn` property true/false.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
bool IsSignedIn{get;set;}
}

@model MyViewModel

<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
@if(Model.IsSignedIn)
{
        <li><a href="/home.html?sign=true">Home</a></li>
}
        <li><a href="/jobs.html">Tests</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vps.html">Jobs1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ust.html">Jobs2</a></li>
@if(Model.IsSignedIn)
{
        <li><a href="/sub.html">Subscription</a></li>  
}                
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

AS mentioned by @Rory you should prefer it doing on server side.
However if you want to do it in JQuery then make sure your href have an unique id.
Suppose your id for Home link is 'home' then you can use
`$('#home').Hide()` and similarly `$('#home').Show()` to make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION)){
        <li><a href="/home.html?sign=true">Home</a></li>
} ?>
        <li><a href="/jobs.html">Tests</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vps.html">Jobs1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ust.html">Jobs2</a></li>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION)){
        <li><a href="/sub.html">Subscription</a></li>  
} ?>                
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not at all recommended mate.This is through `jQuery`(Not recommended)
if you loginpage is `examplesite.com/loginpage`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("loginpage") > -1) { //Checks if the url has loginpage string
       $('#navigation ul li:first').hide();
       $('#navigation ul li:last').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to do it on client-side. You should do it based on the authorization.

Though you can do it on client side like this :

```
jQuery('#navigation ul li:first').hide();
jQuery('#navigation ul li:last').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

> i mean i have session variables for signed user name and other
>    details.so using this how can i hide the link details –  Sush

As you are having session variables, you can use the same to hide the links. This can be achieved using an if condition.

Only if the session variable containing user details is not empty, display the links.
You can use scripts.

```
if(session.username>0)
{
<a href="/home.html?sign=true">Home</a>
<a href="/sub.html">Subscription</a>
}
```

This is not the correct syntax. Just an example for the illustration.

Answer (score 0):

add a new script in your sign-in page and it should be at last in order of scripts so that it can override other scripts like this

```
<head>
 <script></script>
 <script></scrtipt>
 <script src="hide.js"></script>
</head>
```

and now write the code to hide the links in `hide.js`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#navigation ul').children('li').each(function()
   {
       if($(this).children('a').text()=='Home' || $(this).children('a').text()=='Subscriptions')
       {
          $(this).hide();
       }
   })
})
```